# How to get Posts filtered by hashtag using Realm.io in objective c?

Tags: ios, realm

I have the Post and Hashtag classes like this.

```
@interface Post : RLMObject
@property NSString *uID;
.....
@property RLMArray<GAHashtag *><GAHashtag> *hashtagsArray;
@end

@interface Hashtag : RLMObject
@property NSString *uID;
@property NSString *text;
@property NSInteger postsCount;
@end
```

Can i get Posts list filtered by Hashtag text or uID? 
For example

```
NSString *hashtagText = @"hello";    
RLMResults *results = [Post objectsWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hashtagsArray.text ?=? %@", hashtagText]];
```

Thanks.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can filter posts by hashtag or uID using `ANY` operator. Please try like following:

```
RLMResults *results = [Post objectsWhere:@"ANY hashtagsArray.text = %@", hashtagText];
```